# unshare network with loopback enabled

Tags: linux-namespaces, unshare

To run tests on the development build of my program I need to isolate it from the network.
The build still needs access to `loopback` (127.0.0.1) though.

I tried using `unshare -c -n <program>` but the loopback interface is down by default.
Using `unshare -r -n bash` allows me to enable the interface by using `ip link set lo up` but the program needs to be invoked manually in *that* `bash` shell then.

I tried to create a persistent network namespace (`ip netns add vnet1`) but that only works with `sudo` which I need to avoid.

So it is possible to create a unshared network namespace with `lo` down, without using  `sudo`.

I need to get the `lo` interface up before launching the build. Ideally I'd integrate the the setup in a bash script **without** using privilege escalation.
I've read that fedora provides a enabled loopback interface by default, so can I adjust this behavior with `sysctl` etc. ? (I'm on archlinux)